# rake db:migrate aborted due to version differences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I am trying to load my rails app in localhost:3000 however I've run into a few errors related to my rake versioning.

When I launch my server with `rails server` and then I refresh in the browser, this error shows up in my server logs:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError - Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.:
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `check_pending!'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `run__4154752559951713534__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

However, when I follow the error's advice and run `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` I get the following error:

```
Aarons-iMac:ripelist-classifieds AaronWilliamson$ bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
== 20140424074405 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:442:in `block in log'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:437:in `log'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:360:in `add_column'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:488:in `each'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:488:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/db/migrate/20140424074405_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:334:in `change_table'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:629:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `say_with_time'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:387:in `method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/db/migrate/20140424074405_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:538:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `exec_migration'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `block in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:557:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:713:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:963:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:962:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:924:in `block in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `each'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:746:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:442:in `block in log'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:437:in `log'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:360:in `add_column'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:488:in `each'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:488:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/db/migrate/20140424074405_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:334:in `change_table'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:629:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `say_with_time'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:387:in `method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/db/migrate/20140424074405_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:538:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `exec_migration'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `block in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:557:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:713:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:963:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:962:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:924:in `block in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `each'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:746:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users" already exists
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:442:in `block in log'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:437:in `log'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:360:in `add_column'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:488:in `each'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:488:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/db/migrate/20140424074405_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:334:in `change_table'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:629:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `say_with_time'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:387:in `method_missing'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/db/migrate/20140424074405_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:538:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `exec_migration'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `block in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:557:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:713:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:963:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:962:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:924:in `block in migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `each'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `up'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:746:in `migrate'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Also, when I try to run a simple command like `rake routes` I get this error:

```
Aarons-iMac:ripelist-classifieds AaronWilliamson$ rake routes
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.2.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Ripelist-Classifieds/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras'
gem 'email_validator'
gem 'devise'
gem 'dimensions-rails'
gem 'unicorn'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'letter_opener'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

I am using rails version 4.0.4

I am using ruby version 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

I am fairly new to rails so layman's terms would be greatly appreciated to help me understand the problem. I just want to get my app running and my rake configuration back on track.

Comment: What happens when you run `bundle install`? Does that fix your `rake routes` issue? I think you have two separate problems here...your routes don't depend on the current state of your database.

Comment: `bundle exec rake routes` will work. When you are doing migration, the email column in the users table already there and through your migration, you are trying to add another email column to users. That's why you are getting the errors

Comment: I ran `bundle` and `bundle install` but that didn't fix anything. 'bundle exec rake routes' seems to give me the routes but it doesn't do anything else. The main error I need help with is this one:

    Aarons-iMac:ripelist-classifieds AaronWilliamson$ rake db:create
    rake aborted!
    Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.2.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

I don't understand this error and I want to have it where I don't need to run `bundle exec`.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is with the gem **rake**, just update this Gem with the command `bundle update rake` and it would solve the problem while running the **Migration.**

Answer (score 0):

From you log:

> PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users"
>   already exists

This mean in last migration `20140424074405 AddDeviseToUsers` you try create column that already exists.

Try delete this migration.
About rake also from log:

> You have already activated rake 10.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rake
>   10.2.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

This mean then you run `rake routes` it is execute rake installed on system not in project for run inside project use `bundle exec rake routes`

Comment: I never had to use `bundle exec` before, do you know how I can get back to using just `rake routes` or even `rake db:create` since that's not even working?